# Parsing just a column of a CSV file with multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

I am learning Python and am currently working with it to parse a CSV file.

The CSV file has 3 columns:

```
Full_name, university, and Birth_Year.
```

I have successfully loaded,read, and printed the content of a given CSV file into Python, but here’s where I am stuck at:

- I want to use and parse **ONLY** the column `Full_name` to 3 columns: `first, middle, and last`. If there are only 2 words in the name, then the middle name should be null.
- The resulting parsed output should then be inserted to a sql db through Python.

Here’s my code so far:

```
import csv
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len (sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Please enter the csv file too: python name_parsing.py student_info.csv")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        with open(sys.argv[1], "r" ) as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file) #I use DictReader because the csv file has > 1 col

            # Print the names on the cmd
            for row in reader:
                name = row["Full_name"]
                for name in reader:
                    if len(name) == 2:
                        print(first_name = name[0])
                        print(middle_name = None)
                        print(last_name = name[2])
                    if len(name) == 3 : # The assumption is that name is either 2 or 3 words only.
                        print(first_name = name[0])
                        print(middle_name = name[1])
                        print(last_name = name[2])

db.execute("INSERT INTO name (first, middle, last) VALUES(?,?,?)",
            row["first_name"], row["middle_name"], row["last_name"])
```

Running the program above gives me no output whatsoever. How to parse my code the right way? Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you have two nested loops over `reader` and immediately shadow `name = row["Full_name"]` with the loop variable in the inner loop. I'd strongly recommend stepping through this with a debugger. Also *"I use DictReader because the csv file has > 1 col"* - a CSV file with a single column is just a file...

Comment: Hi jonsharpe, thanks for your answer. I am still learning python though, so I probably misinterpreted the use case of csv reader and csv.dictreader I gather from googling online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample file based on your description. The content looks as below:

```
Full_name,University,Birth_Year
Prakash Ranjan Gupta,BPUT,1920
Hari Shankar,NIT,1980
John Andrews,MIT,1950
Arbaaz Aslam Khan,REC,2005
```

And then I executed the code below. It runs fine on my jupyter notebook. You can add the lines (sys.argv) != 2 etc) with this as you need. I have used sqlite3 database I hope this works. In case you want the if/main block added to this, let me know: can edit.
This is going by your code. (Otherwise You can do this using pandas in an easier way I believe.)

```
import csv
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('name_data.sql') ## Make DB connection and create a table if it does not exist
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UNIV_DATA 
(FIRSTNAME TEXT, 
MIDDLE_NAME TEXT,
LASTNAME TEXT, 
UNIVERSITY TEXT, 
YEAR TEXT)''')

with open('names_data.csv') as fh:
    read_data = csv.DictReader(fh)    
    for uniData in read_data:
        lst_nm = uniData['Full_name'].split()
        if len(lst_nm) == 2:
            fn,ln = lst_nm
            mn = None
        else:
            fn,mn,ln = lst_nm
#         print(fn,mn,ln,uniData['University'],uniData['Birth_Year'] )
        cur.execute('''
        INSERT INTO UNIV_DATA
        (FIRSTNAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LASTNAME, UNIVERSITY, YEAR)
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)''', 
        (fn,mn,ln,uniData['University'],uniData['Birth_Year'])
        )
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

If you want to read the data in the table UNIV_DATA:

Option 1: (prints the rows in the form of tuple)

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('name_data.sql') #Make connection to DB and create a connection object
cur = con.cursor() #Create a cursor object
results = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM UNIV_DATA') # Execute the query and store the rows retrieved in 'result'
[print(result) for result in results]  #Traverse through 'result' in a loop to print the rows retrieved  
cur.close() #close the cursor
con.close() #close the connection
```

Option 2: (prints all the rows in the form of a pandas data frame - execute in jupyter ...preferably )

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
con = sqlite3.connect('name_data.sql') #Make connection to DB and create a connection object
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM UNIV_DATA', con) #Query the table and store the result in a dataframe : df
df
```

Comment: Hi @instinct246, thank you so much for your help! This code works the way I wanted it to be! Thanks again for your help! BTW if I want to query this db from another python file, how can I do so? Like db.execute (SELECT * FROM univ_data)

Comment: @speedy_catch Edited  my post to answer your new question. Pls take a look.

Comment: Thanks @instinct246 for your help. I have re-worded the problem in this other question if you'd like to answer and help (again). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816989/print-out-the-result-of-sqlite-database-query-with-a-format Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `name = row["Full_name"]` it is going to return a string representing the name, e.g. "John Smith".

In python strings can be treated like lists, so in this case if you called `len(name)` it would return 10 as "John Smith" has 10 characters. As this doesn't equal 2 or 3, nothing will happen in your for loop.

What you need is some way to turn the string into a list that containing the first, second and last names. You can do this using the split function. If you call `name.split(" ")` it would split the string whenever there is a space, continuing the above example this would return `["John", "Smith"]` which should make your code work.