# Print out the result of sqlite database query with a format

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this student db with four columns: `first_name, middle_name, last_name, school, birth_year`. 
I have successfully read the content of the db using SELECT statement, but here's where I got stuck at:

How do I print the query result with the format like this:
`first_name middle_name(if available) last_name was born in birth_year`?
So for every row in the query the intended result should do this: `Aida Blue was born in 1985`.

For now if I run `print(all_rows)` the code will print the query result like this: `[{'first_name':'Aida', 'middle_name': None, 'last_name': 'Blue', 'school': 'Washington', 'birth_year': 1981}, {...}, ....]`

Below is my code attempt at such problem:

```
db = cs.SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python student_school.py school")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        school = str(sys.argv[1])
        all_rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE school=?", school)
        first = all_rows[:][0] #I want to pick up the first col
        middle = all_rows[:][1] #if value <> None?
        last= all_rows[:][2]
        birth_year = all_rows[:][4]
        print(first_name, " " , middle_name, " ", last_name, "was born in ", birth_year \n)
```

Can anyone please advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your `all_rows` variable list of dictionaries. Each dict representing a student record.
- You can write a for loop to iterate over it and print each one.
- Also in print statement when you write ',' it will automatically put seperater to  (single space). There is no need to explicitly write `" "`. Same with `\n` there is no need to explicitly write '\n'. Read more here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print.

```py
db = cs.SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python student_school.py school")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        school = str(sys.argv[1])
        all_rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE school=?", school)
        for student in all_rows:
            print(student['first_name'], student['middle_name'] if student['middle_name'] else '', student['last_name'], "was born in", student['birth_year'])
```

Comment: HI @Poojan, thanks for the answer. Your answer seems to help, except there are rows where `middle_name` is Null in my database. How do I manage this with your code? Thanks again

Comment: @speedy_catch You can write inline if condition to check if value is None. If None value print '' empty string. Check above edited answer it should work for your case.

Comment: no worries, they work now. Thanks a lot again for your help!